# Geometry problem - lines/piece wise defined function

Tags: geometry

I am bothered by a certain problem. Suppose $x$ lines are drawn in the plane where no two of them are parallel and no three or more meet at one point. How many unbounded regions are there? Its pretty easy to see that if we started with the case $x = 0$ we get $1$ unbounded region. With $x = 1$ we get $2$ unbounded regions, etc. The general pattern is $1,2,4,6,8,10,...$ Why does this bother me? Because clearly if it wasn't for the first case we would get that for $x$ lines there is $2x$ unbounded regions. Now I could make a piece wise defined function to account for the first case but my question is, can a function like $2x$ be made such that it in fact incorporates the first case with all the other cases?

The total number of regions is $\displaystyle\frac{x^2 + x + 2}{2}$. If I knew how to find a single function for the unbounded regions I could just subtract the bounded region function from the total number to see what the bounded function is.

Comment: What kind of function "like $2x$" are you looking for? No linear or quadratic or polynomial formula exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could have $$2x+0^x$$ where $0^0$ is taken to be $1$,

similar to the the binomial expansion $\displaystyle (1+y)^n = \sum_{x=0}^{n} {n \choose x}y^x$ when letting $y=0$.